# On the condition of $ac$ when factoring a quadratic trinomial where $a\neq1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am currently reading the section "Factoring quadratic trinomials when a ≠ 1 using the grouping method" [this](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/factoring_3.htm#anchor) site. I don't understand the last part of this paragraph:

[image]

Where did the condition for $ac$ come from?

I thought the extra conditions would be $a=pr$, $c=qs$ as I that is how I read the condition for $b$ too ie. $b=ps+pr$.

Lastly, why is it $ac$ and not some other arithmetic operation e.g. $a+c$ or $a/c$?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the following easy (Viéte...)

**Lemma:** If $\;\alpha\,,\,\beta\;$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $\;ax^2+bx+c=0\;$ , then

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

**Proof:** Just write

$$\alpha=\frac{-b-\sqrt\Delta}{2a}\;\;,\;\;\;\beta=\frac{-b+\sqrt\Delta}{2a}\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\Delta:=b^2-4ac$$

and do a little algebra.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the connection between $ac$ and the lemma

Comment: Read carefully in the line under "right hand side" . From there you get $$\;a=pr\;,\;\;c=qs\implies ac=prqs=(ps)(qr)$$

Comment: Yes, i see that implication. Where does the lemma come in?

Comment: It's exactly what's being used to reach the equation just below where's written "...be factored like this:" !

Comment: The lemma says $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ but the question was $ax^2 + bx + c = (px+q)(rx+s)$ How do I translate between the two. I've done the algebra to prove the lemma. Does that help?

Comment: For the benefit of future users who may have this question, this site has a useful explanation too: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69515.html

Comment: @mauna, just observe that $$(px+q)(rx+s)=pq\left(x+\frac qp\right)\left(x+\frac sr\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$u$ is any number

$\frac{b}2 + u$ multiplied by $\frac{b}2 -u$ will give you $c$.

$\frac{b}2 + u$  added to $\frac{b}2 -u$ will give you $b$.

Solve for $u$  then substitute $\frac{b}2 \pm u$.

The two numbers you get are the solution

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math thank you.